# Unable to run npm link

Tags: hyperlink, npm, generator, yeoman

I'm trying to develop a yeoman generator

To test my generator locally I need to run `npm link`

I tried running `sudo npm link` to no avail.

I have pasted the output of `cat npm-debug.log`

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'link' ]
2 info using npm@2.0.0-alpha-5
3 info using node@v0.10.29
4 verbose node symlink /usr/local/bin/node
5 verbose linkPkg /Users/sourabhshirhatti/ms/yo/generator-aspnet
6 error Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/sourabhshirhatti/ms/yo/generator-aspnet/package.json'
7 error If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
7 error including the npm and node versions, at:
7 error     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
8 error System Darwin 13.3.0
9 error command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "link"
10 error cwd /Users/sourabhshirhatti/ms/yo/generator-aspnet
11 error node -v v0.10.29
12 error npm -v 2.0.0-alpha-5
13 error path /Users/sourabhshirhatti/ms/yo/generator-aspnet/package.json
14 error code ENOENT
15 error errno 34
16 verbose exit [ 34, true ]
```

Do you folks know how fix this error?